# How to add a project as a [jar] module depndency

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

---

### Update:

Upon further investigation, I found the issue
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-66523/jvmMain-resources-classpath-is-not-added-when-using-the-multiplatform-project-as-a-module

The resource classpath is not added when consumed by adding

```
    implementation(project(":sevenzipJavm"))
```

but when the jar is added then I can access the resources.

So, now unless the issue is fixed by JetBrains the current best workaround is to consume the project as a jar instead of classes.
but this brings us to a new problem as it seems there is no easy way of adding as a jar. even when I do

```kotlin
  implementation(files("../sevenzipJavm/build/libs/sevenzipJavm-jvm.jar"))
```

It still uses build\classes. The only way I can make it use the jar is to move it out of the project and then link it

```kotlin
implementation(files("D:/x/sevenzipJavm-jvm.jar"))
```

This is very cumbersome as I need to manually build and move it every time I change something.

Thus, I have also updated the problem title.
Again don't show me how to add a project as classes but as a jar and not staticly by moving it elsewhere.

---

### Old for reference:

It seems I can't access the resources of src\jvmMain\resources\a.txt in jvmMain of the multiplatform project.

gradle kts:

```kotlin
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.android.library)
//    id("module.publication")
}

kotlin {
    applyDefaultHierarchyTemplate()
    jvm()


    androidTarget {

        publishLibraryVariants("release")
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }

//    iosX64()
//    iosArm64()
//    iosSimulatorArm64()
//    linuxX64()

    sourceSets {

        commonMain.dependencies {


        }

        commonTest.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
        }

        androidMain.dependencies {
        }

        jvmMain {
            dependencies {
            }

        }


    }
}

android {
    namespace = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx.multiplatform.library.sevenZip"
    compileSdk = libs.versions.android.compileSdk.get().toInt()
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = libs.versions.android.minSdk.get().toInt()
    }
}
```

sample:

```kotlin
        val message =
            Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader.getResource("a.txt")?.readText()
        println(message)
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here? and how to fix it.
This code works on pure JVM projects if is not inside multiplatform.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader.getResource("a.txt")?.readText()
```

Do this,

```
this.javaClass.classLoader.getResource("a.txt")?.readText()
```

I just tested it and it works.

Comment: >I just tested it and it works. 
Have you tried it on JVM project that is inside a Kotlin multiplatform project and the resource is inside jvmMain\resources? if not then it works for me too, as I've already said in OP.

Comment: I tried exactly that. I created a KMP library, add jvm target along with android and ios. then Added resources in jvmMain, added a text file with content "hello" and then wrote a unit test in jvmTest to get the content of the file and asserted the value. @CyberAvater

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I can access the resources when in test but not when adding the project in library dependency for another project by
implementation(project(":process"))
I'm updating the op